# When removing a file it still is present on the machine

Tags: nodes, files

When deleting a node the files attached to that node are removed from the server just fine. However if I edit the node and remove the file there, it stays on the server even after deleting the node.

Is this normal? Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permanent files have a status [`FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/constant/FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT/7).

> Indicates that the file is permanent and should not be deleted.
>
> Temporary files older than `DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE` will be
>   removed during cron runs, but permanent files will not be removed
>   during the file garbage collection process.

When you remove a file from a node, the file_managed record may simply be marked as `status = 0` or anything other than `FILE_PERMANENT`, in which case, it's deleted during [`system_cron`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_cron/7) (if no entry in the `file_usage` table).

Basically, if you have cron running, it should be fine.